# Espresso: Test Activity showing selected Image from Gallery

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have the following problem in my Android App:

I have got a Fragment (hosted in MainActivity) which contains an ImageButton. Once clicked, It opens the Gallery via startActivityForResult. When the user selects an Image from Gallery, the Gallery itself gets closed and the selected Image gets shown into a DialogActivity.

All is working perfectly on Runtime.

How can I test this situation using Espresso?

Thank you all in advance.

*Please note*: searching in stack overflow I found nothing that could match what I was looking for.

Comment: With espresso you can just test your own app, but you can not interact with the gallery app that you open. For this you have to use some other testing framework like ui-automator additionally. So test your own app with espresso but do the image selection with ui-automator

Comment: I never used It. Can you please provide me some code snippets for My case so I Can Implement It the right way? Thank you very much

Comment: of course, here you should find everything to get started with ui automator: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this could very well be tested in Espresso, if you split your test case into two parts:

- Verifying that the app opens the Gallery app
- Verifying that the app opens the DialogActivity when an image is selected

For the first part, you can use [espresso-intents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/). Basically, you would assert that the corresponding intent was sent.

Assuming you start the Gallery app like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

You could test it using:

```
intended(allOf(hasAction(equalTo(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)),
               hasType(is("image/*"))))
```

For the second part, and since it is the MainActivity that is handling the `onActivityResult`, you could create a `@VisibleForTesting` public method that calls your `onActivityResult`, and you pass to it an intent that contains your image. Finally, call said public method through your `@Rule MainActivityTestRule`.